# Cannot access a disposed object Object name: 'UserManager`1'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I realize that this question is ask quite a few times on stack Overflow but i tried a few answer but non solve my issue.I just recently added unity into my project, everything work fine except for the userManager class. If i try to access it in session it throws a Cannot access error as stated in my title.

```
   The Code that is throwing the issues and the Container below

    public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;

        // Start of new code
        UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
        };
    }



        container.RegisterType<AdminController>();
        container.RegisterType<AccountController>();
        container.RegisterType<IBlogPostRepository, BlogPostRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IBlogViewRepository, BlogViewRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<ITagRepository, TagRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IBlogCategoryRepository, BlogCategoryRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IBlogTagRepository, BlogTagRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IApplicationUserRepository, ApplicationUserRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new InjectionConstructor(new CatchMediaContext()));
        container.RegisterType<DbContext, CatchMediaContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: i remove the line @SAm it does not solve the issue.

Comment: If another object has a reference to userManager and that object is disposed, it might be disposing userManager along with it.  Another possibility is userManager requires some type of initialization which hasn't been done yet, and its properties throw a misleading disposed exception (this is common with winform controls).

Comment: Look through your code for all 'using' blocks and calls to Dipose().  As well, if this is part of a multi-threaded program, make sure userManager is assigned to a member field so that it isn't garbage collected.

Comment: Do you want to roll this into an answer so others can benefit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If another object has a reference to userManager and that object is disposed, it might be disposing userManager along with it.  Another possibility is userManager requires some type of initialization which hasn't been done yet, and its properties throw a misleading disposed exception (this is common with winform controls).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error. 
My discovery: the parent partial tried to render two forms. The two forms are created by calling their respective actions in different controllers. BUT the different controllers BOTH referenced `UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager`. 
My solution: simply removed one form thus the page has only one reference to `UserManager`.